# C++: Storing std::set_union() output in a std::multiset

Tags: c++, std, multiset

I want to perform a `union` operation between two `multisets`.

However, at the moment I have been able to figure out only to store the output of the operation into a `std::vector`, and then I have to convert a vector to a multiset.

This conversion from my tests is very expensive and I would like to avoid that because I need the output as a multiset.

How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    multiset<int> m, p;
    m.insert(4);
    m.insert(4);
    m.insert(2);
    m.insert(1);
    m.insert(7);

    p.insert(2);
    p.insert(2);
    p.insert(2);
    p.insert(1);
    p.insert(5);

    vector<int> v;
    set_union(m.begin(), m.end(), p.begin(), p.end(), back_inserter(v));

    multiset<int> result(v.begin(), v.end());

    multiset<int>::iterator it;
    for (it=result.begin(); it!=result.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << " ";

    return 0;

}
```

The output is `1 2 2 2 4 4 5 7` as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `std::insert_iterator`. It works like `std::back_inserter`, but just inserts instead of inserting at the back. You can create one by calling `std::inserter(c)`, where `c` is the target container. The first example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) shows an inserter into an `std::multiset`.

Comment: Why does `std::inserter(c, c.end())` need `c.end()` but not `std::back_inserter(c)` ?

Comment: `std::back_inserter` always inserts at `end()`, so you don’t have to say it. Similarly, `std::front_inserter` always inserts at `begin()`.